Hooking Navigator object in Chrome extension detected by antibot detection
I want to spoof some attributes in the Navigator object for experimenting with anti fingerprinting by writing a Chrome extension.
I used techniques discussed here: Access variables and functions defined in page context from an extension
I tried both method 1 and 4. (code below is method 1 modified according to: Chrome Extension: Accessing `window` works on remote websites, but not possible in localhost)
While this changes the User-Agent and seems to actually work it gets detected as a bot on pages like https://www.browserscan.net/bot-detection why is that? Is there any way around it?
Note: The spoofed user agent is same as the authentic user agent to make sure that this is not the problem.
manifest.json
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"name": "Helper",
"description": "Base Level Extension",
"version": "1.0",

"background": {"service_worker": "bg.js"},

"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],

"permissions": [
    "scripting",
    "contentSettings",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess"
],

"declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [{
        "id": "ruleset",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules.json"
    }]
},

"action": {
    "default_popup": "helper.html",
    "default_icon": "helper.png"
}

bg.js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {

const old = await chrome.scripting.getRegisteredContentScripts();

if (old[0]) await chrome.scripting.unregisterContentScripts({ids: old.map(s => s.id)});

await chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts([{
  id: 'write',
  js: ['write.js'],
  matches: ['<all_urls>'],
  runAt: 'document_start',
  world: 'MAIN',
}]);

write.js
var navigator = window.navigator;
var modifiedNavigator;

if ('userAgent' in Navigator.prototype) {
    modifiedNavigator = Navigator.prototype;

} else {
    modifiedNavigator = Object.create(navigator);
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'navigator', {
        value: modifiedNavigator,
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: false
    });
}

console.info(navigator.userAgent)
console.info(navigator.appName)
console.info(navigator.appVersion)
console.info(navigator.platform)

var ua = navigator.userAgent

// I tried this
modifiedNavigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () { return ua; });

// As well as this
Object.defineProperties(modifiedNavigator, {
    userAgent: {
        value: navigator.userAgent.replace(/\([^)]+\)/, 'Windows NT 5.1'),
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: false
    }
});



Use Proxy on top of the original object/function everywhere (to override the objects, functions, getters, everything) instead of __defineGetter__, assignments, and defineProperties. 2) Use declarativeNetRequest API to also change the user agent header and UA-CH headers.


Thank you that worked well. Add as answer if you want, thanks again.

It'd be more useful if you add an answer with your actual code.
